# How can I copy existing class object to other class new class object without creating copy of original object(in memory) in Java

Tags: java, object, memory-management, copy

Please advise.
I think AObj will have only one copy unless we add any changes or update the originally created object within new object. Not sure, please help.

```
public class AObject {
    private String a;
    Private String b;
    
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    

    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
}
public class BObject{
    private AObject aObj;
    public AObject getAObj() {
        return aObj;
    }
    public void setAObj(AObject aObj) {
        this.aObj = aObj;
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args){
    AObject aObj = new AObject();
    aObj.setA("testA");
    aObj.setB("testB");

    BObject bObj = new BObject();
    bObj.setAObj(aObj) //here I would like to avoid creating the deep copy of objects.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not copy the object.  Your code does what you want.

(It is pretty difficult to accidentally copy something in Java.)